# setState on onPressed with null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I have copy this code from bluetooth serial package example and I want to add a setState.

```
FlatButton(
 onPressed: isConnected ? () => 
 _sendMessage('0') : null
)
```

This is what I already tried:

```
FlatButton(
 onPressed:(){
  if(isConnected) 
   _sendMessage('0');
  setState(() {
   counter=true;
  }); 
  }
)
```

But the state didnt change.

What is the correct way on adding setState on this?

Comment: try adding ++counter instead of counter++

Comment: Pardon, i edit my counter to bool.

Comment: can you please post your complete code?

Comment: Your code does not clearly indicate what you are trying to achieve. Please share a working example.